# Check my idea: liminf and limsup definitions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

Let $N\geq 1$ and let $F:\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, radially symmetric and nonnegative function such that:
$$(i): a\in\mathbb{R} \mbox{ exists such that } \liminf_{r\to +\infty}\frac{F(r)}{r^a}>0;\\
(ii): b\in\mathbb{R} \mbox{ exists such that } \limsup_{r\to 0}\frac{F(r)}{r^b}<+\infty.$$

I would like to write conditions $(i)$ and $(ii)$ more convenient. I mean, (in my opinion) condition $(i)$ implies that $C_0\in\mathbb{R}$ exists such that
$$F(r)\geq C_0 r^a\quad\mbox{ if } r\geq C_0$$
whence  condition $(ii)$ implies that $c_0\in\mathbb{R}$ exists such that
$$F(r)\leq c_0 r^b \quad\mbox{ if } 0<r\leq c_0.$$

Does my reasoning hold true? Moreover, could anyone please help me to find a function which satisfies assumptions $(i)$ and $(ii)$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumptions are true but one detail, you have indeed $$
\liminf_{r\to +\infty}\frac{F(r)}{r^a}=l_1>0 \implies \forall \epsilon >0, \exists R , \forall r>R, F(r)>(l-\epsilon)r^a
$$
So you can take $C_0$ to be $l/2$ for example but *it won't be for $r>C_0$ but rather $r>R$ an other constant*.
Idem for your second proposition $$
\limsup_{r\to 0}\frac{F(r)}{r^b}=l_2<+\infty \implies \forall \epsilon \exists R, \forall r < R, F(r)<(l_2+\epsilon)r^b
$$

For a function realizing the two assumptions, given that one limit is in $0$ and the other at $+\infty$, you can take a piecewise function like $$
F(r)=\left \{ \begin{matrix} r^b, r<1 \\
(2^a-1)(r-1)+1, r \in [1,2] \\
r^a,r>2\end{matrix} \right.
$$

In this case $l_1=l_2=1$ and the liminf and limsup become just limits.